# IEnumerator not triggering when start coroutine is called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

So my code is supposed to print this out into the console after 3.5 seconds, but it never happens for some reason.

I have no idea what to try.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Talking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshPro t;
    public Component talk;

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().enableWordWrapping = false;
        StartCoroutine("Speech");
    }

    public IEnumerator Speech()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.5f);
        Debug.Log("yay my code works");
    }
}
```

Comment: is it on an active game object?

Comment: Yes, It is on a active game object

Comment: have you changed the timescale at all? have you put in a debug log to check start is being called?  that it does run the line starting the coroutine

Comment: Is the game object always active?

Comment: Yes, It is always active

Answer (score -1):

try `StartCoroutine(Speech());`
and make sure you script is placed on any object

Comment: It's still not working